# Sort through a sites json and store required info into a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to get data from website.json using the request module I then need to sort through this data and only store that value and this value in a key:value format like this "thatvalue":thisvalue. I need to do this for all the data.

Example data

```
{"number": ewe, "amount": [{"added": 757335, "normal": {"size": 2, "s": "0.021", "ww": "0.37", "fe": "0.15", "gr": 3}, "that": "2354", "d": "0.1", "g": "dwe wew", "ff": "0.2", "this": 4, "dwa": {"ewa": 2, "dass": "0.236", "da": "2.1", "d": "0.6", "tr": 268}, "f2p": false,
```

Current code

```
Helper.update = function(body){
    this.debug("Updating");
    request("website.json", {json: true},
    console.log(body),  
    );
}
```

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is bad about the way I asked it?

Comment: There is no `appid` or `true_count` in your example data. I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: Hey, sorry forgot to update it, had to make it more vague, should be understandable now.

Comment: Please fix your example data, it is neither valid JSON nor a valid object literal.

Comment: I've tried to google for sulutions but I can't find anything for my specific senario, I've tried a couple things but none have worked. this was something I made a while ago that no longer works and I would like to try to get atleast this part working again. I haven't really coded in a while so I've forgot a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is a quick example using lodash:

```
let obj = _.map(data.amount, function(item){
  let _this = item.this;
  let _that = item.that;
  return { [_this]: _that }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Working demo (with a valid arbitrary json object): https://jsfiddle.net/xzq1Ldbp/

Using Array.prototype.map, without external libraries:

```
let obj = data.amount.map(function(item){
  let _this = item.this;
  let _that = item.that;
  return { [_this]: _that }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Hey, I really appreicate your help, I'm not very advanced and I've been struggling on and off to fix this for a couple weeks. I try to be as kind as possible as I don't really know that much and feel like people are being very condescending towards me. Thanks!